# Canvas clearRect not erasing all of my lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using clearRect to erase and redraw lines on a canvas, but occasionally lines will remain. I don't know where I'm going wrong. I have uploaded a demo here. This is a screenshot of the problem:

http://zackseuberling.com/screenshots/screen_shot_2011-10-27_at_11.19.29_am_bd26.png

I'm passing in the lines to draw as a multi-tiered array like this

```
    all_curves = [
            ['down_right',
                    [255, 250, 100, 40]
            ],
            ['right_down',
                    [355, 290, 330, 245]
            ]
    ]
```

where the "down_right", etc. is the curve path, and the array of integers is the x, y, length and height of the curves.

this is the code that draws the lines

```
    for(each_line in all_curves){
            mask_draw(this, all_curves[each_line][0], all_curves[each_line][1][0], all_curves[each_line][1][1], all_curves[each_line][1][2], all_curves[each_line][1][3]);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the source code so that I may know what you have done wrong.

Comment: I've added some code snippets, but the all of the drawing is wrapped in a drawing object. the whole thing is available here: http://rumors-studio.com/test/Spheres-of-Influence_Stack_2/js/lines.js

Comment: Okay, I've seen your source code and from what I understand you are using 4 separate canvas elements - one for mobile devices (pink), one for interface devices (green), one for personal devices (blue), and one for the mask when a certain device is clicked and the pop-up appears (grey). On clicking a device the first three canvas elements are redrawn as black and the mask shows the path to the device from the top. Now, from your screen-shot I can see that extra mask paths are being drawn. I think this is because of using jQuery events and multiple canvas elements. This along those lines.

Comment: I'll try to create a local web page, solve your problems and upload the results for you. However, it may take a while as I'm a little busy today.

Comment: wow, thank you so much. I was drawing the large black rectangle and then using clearRect in the thought that if the lines were drawn over, the clearRect would erase them. unfortunately, that is not how it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your code, and I believe it works properly. The problem in my opinion was the use multiple canvas elements and overlaying them using CSS. I have uploaded the [zip](http://www.mediafire.com/?at6epw6nl74fl8a) archive on [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/), so you may download it from there. I have only made changes to the `index.html` file and I have created a new `stack.js` file in the `js` folder. If you have any queries then feel free to ask me. Hope this helps.